# when try to add event receiver to production facing this issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I have create event receiver in dev environment and its working fine. But when try to add in production facing:

```
PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://site/hr
PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spList = $spWeb.Lists["EmpEntyExit"]

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spEventReceiver = $spList.EventReceivers.Add()

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spEventReceiver.Assembly = "$SharePoint.Project.Assemb
lyFullName$"

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spEventReceiver.Class = "my_STG.AddTaskand_SubTask
.AddTaskand_SubTask"

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spEventReceiver.Name = "AddTaskand_SubTaskItemAdded"


PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spEventReceiver.Type = 10002

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spEventReceiver.SequenceNumber = 1000

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spEventReceiver.Synchronization = 1

PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin> $spEventReceiver.Update()
```

> Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Could not load file
>   or assembly '.Project.AssemblyFullName$' or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified." At line:1 char:1
>   + $spEventReceiver.Update()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
>
> PS C:\Users\spfarmadmin>

Comment: You can try providing assembly name like $spEventReceiver.Assembly = "YourAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5eff...(here goes assebly's token"     "$SharePoint.Project.Assemb lyFullName$" is resolved when you use visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

`$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` is a [replacement token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231545.aspx) that VisualStudio will automatically replace with the real 4-part name of your assembly when you build the project.

What you can do is add a little Powershell snippet as an "external tool" in your Tools menu in VisualStudio which will output the 4-part assembly full name to the Output window in VS. [Link here to the instructions on how to do that.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/2010/11/05/quick-tip-find-the-four-part-name-for-an-assembly/)

You can then use that information (the real 4-part name) in your Powershell above for adding the event receiver in production.